# Django-Admin: list_filter attribute from UserProfile

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to allow the admins of my site to filter users from a specific country on the Admin Site. So the natural thing to do would be something like this:

```
#admin.py
class UserAdmin(django.contrib.auth.admin.UserAdmin):
    list_filter=('userprofile__country__name',)

#models.py
class UserProfile(models.Model)
    ...
    country=models.ForeignKey('Country')

class Country(models.Model)
    ...
    name=models.CharField(max_length=32)
```

But, because of the way Users and their UserProfiles are handled in django this leads to the following error:

```
'UserAdmin.list_filter[0]' refers to field 'userprofile__country__name' that is missing from model 'User'
```

How do I get around this limitation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you are looking for is *custom admin FilterSpecs*. The bad news is, the support for those might not supposed to ship soon (you can track the discussion [here](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/5833)).

However, at the price of a dirty hack, you can workaround the limitation. Some highlights on how `FilterSpecs` are built before diving in the code :

- When building the list of `FilterSpec` to display on the page, Django uses the list of fields you provided in `list_filter`
- Those fields needs to be *real* fields on the model, not reverse relationship, nor custom properties.
- Django maintains a list of `FilterSpec` classes, each associated with a *test* function.
- For each fields in `list_filter`, Django will use  the first `FilterSpec` class for which the *test* function returns **True** for the field.

Ok, now with this in mind, have a look at the following code. It is adapted from [a django snippet](http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1051/). The organization of the code is left to your discretion, just keep in mind this should be imported by the `admin` app.

```
from myapp.models import UserProfile, Country
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

from django.contrib.admin.filterspecs import FilterSpec, ChoicesFilterSpec
from django.utils.encoding import smart_unicode
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class ProfileCountryFilterSpec(ChoicesFilterSpec):
    def __init__(self, f, request, params, model, model_admin):
        ChoicesFilterSpec.__init__(self, f, request, params, model, model_admin)

        # The lookup string that will be added to the queryset
        # by this filter
        self.lookup_kwarg = 'userprofile__country__name'
        # get the current filter value from GET (we will use it to know
        # which filter item is selected)
        self.lookup_val = request.GET.get(self.lookup_kwarg)

        # Prepare the list of unique, country name, ordered alphabetically
        country_qs = Country.objects.distinct().order_by('name')
        self.lookup_choices = country_qs.values_list('name', flat=True)

    def choices(self, cl):
        # Generator that returns all the possible item in the filter
        # including an 'All' item.
        yield { 'selected': self.lookup_val is None,
                'query_string': cl.get_query_string({}, [self.lookup_kwarg]),
                'display': _('All') }
        for val in self.lookup_choices:
            yield { 'selected' : smart_unicode(val) == self.lookup_val,
                    'query_string': cl.get_query_string({self.lookup_kwarg: val}),
                    'display': val }

    def title(self):
        # return the title displayed above your filter
        return _('user\'s country')

# Here, we insert the new FilterSpec at the first position, to be sure
# it gets picked up before any other
FilterSpec.filter_specs.insert(0,
  # If the field has a `profilecountry_filter` attribute set to True
  # the this FilterSpec will be used
  (lambda f: getattr(f, 'profilecountry_filter', False), ProfileCountryFilterSpec)
)


# Now, how to use this filter in UserAdmin,
# We have to use one of the field of User model and
# add a profilecountry_filter attribute to it.
# This field will then activate the country filter if we
# place it in `list_filter`, but we won't be able to use
# it in its own filter anymore.

User._meta.get_field('email').profilecountry_filter = True

class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
  list_filter = ('email',) + UserAdmin.list_filter

# register the new UserAdmin
from django.contrib.admin import site
site.unregister(User)
site.register(User, MyUserAdmin)
```

It's clearly not a panacea but it will do the job, waiting for a better solution to come up.(for example, one that will subclass `ChangeList` and override `get_filters`).

Comment: Thanks, I'm stuck with Django 1.2 on a project and this was really helpful.  Two notes:


1) The "userprofile__" bit in the above is derived from the model name of the user profile class.  My profile class is called Profile, so in my case I want "profile__country__name" -- took me a minute to figure that out.


2) For the general case, you need to also override the ModelAdmin's `lookup_allowed` method to prevent SuspiciousOperation exceptions when doing lookups on the relation.  http://www.hoboes.com/Mimsy/hacks/fixing-django-124s-suspiciousoperation-filtering/ helped here.

Answer (score 5):

Django 1.3 fixed it. You're now allowed to span relations in list_filter

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter