# django admin custom list_filter: Is Null/Not Null choices

Tags: django, django-admin-filters

I have a model:

```
class Label ( TimeStampAwareModel ):
     name = models.CharField ( max_length = 255, blank = False )
     slug = models.CharField ( max_length = 255, blank = True, null = True ) 
     description = models.TextField () 
     logo = ImageField ( upload_to = 'images/labels', null=True, blank=True)
```

Now i want apply filter for logo, slug and desc. i found [this](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1963/), but i don't know how to apply it on my code?

is there anyone knows the other solution or tell me how to use [this](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1963/) snippet?
I am using django 1.3.

Thanks :)

Comment: you want to filter the query set? by avoiding null or none values? your question is not clear..

Comment: i have updated the question. I want a custom list_filter in django admin sidebar, having these fields (slug, logo etc.)

Comment: Thats make more sense now, see my answer :)

Answer (score -1):

in your admin.py do the following:

```
from django.contrib import admin

from project.app.models import Label // where project is your project name and app is your application name, you change this accordingly


class Label_Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = ['slug', 'logo', 'description']

admin.site.register(Label, Label_Admin)
```

Thats all you need, hope this helps.

**Edited**

for custom filter please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251851/django-admin-list-filter-attribute-from-userprofile) post.

Comment: I want these Is_Null/Not_Null choices, like we have in Boolean field

Comment: i have edited my post please check it, may be it give you the solution

Comment: exactly i need this http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2229/, but i don't know how to apply it on my model admin??

Comment: He's not asking how to setup a ModelAdmin. Obviously, he already knows how to do that. He was asking how to filter records by a column's Null/NotNull value. Admin doesn't automatically do that, even if you list the columns in list_filter.